# How do I make src/test/resources files available to other projects' unit tests?

Tags: java, maven, testing, resources

For example, there is a project *my-common* which contains a *my.properties* file in *src/main/resources* and another version *src/test/resources*, which is used for tests.

Then there are other projects, for example *my-service*, which uses *my-common* and the *src/main/resources/my.properties* values.

How can I make the *src/test/resources/my.properties* available to unit tests in *my-services/src/test/java*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Maven way to to this is to [create a test jar](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html). The maven plugin *maven-jar-plugin* is used with the goal *test-jar*:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

You would then need to depend on the test jar in the modules where you need to:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>groupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <version>version</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```